# ¿Cómo guardar las iteraciones realizadas a partir de un While en un data frame en R?

Tags: r

estoy haciendo este while. Necesito que el resultado de la iteración me lo guarde en un data frame. Alguien tiene idea qué sentencia me conviene usar? 
Desde ya gracias!!

```
correct <- 0
i <- 1
customer <- rosco_filter$user_id[1]



 while (i <= nrow(rosco_filter)) {
  if (customer == rosco_filter$user_id[i] &
      rosco_filter$flag_correct[i] == 1) {
    correct <- correct + 1
  }

  else{
    print(c(correct,rosco_filter$event_time[i], customer))

    correct <- 0
    customer <- rosco_filter$user_id[i]
  }

  i <- i + 1
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Conceptualmente necesitas ir "acumulando" resultados con cada iteración, una forma bastante óptima es usar una lista para guardar los resultados:

```
resultados <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(rosco_filter)) {
  # Acumulamos resultados en la lista
  resultados[[i]]  <- data.frame(v1=correct, v2=rosco_filter$event_time[i], v3=customer)
}
do.call(rbind, resultados)
```

El código, a fines didácticos, esta simplificado a las sentencias que nos interesan al problema. Veamos algunos comentarios:

- Antes del ciclo, creamos una lista vacía: `resultados <- list()`
- En tu caso, es más práctico usar un `for` que un `while` ya que estás iterando por el número de fila, con el `for` evitas declarar la variable `i` y acumularla al final del ciclo.
- Vamos agregando un nuevo elemento a la lista mediante: `resultados[[i]]  <- data.frame(v1=correct, v2=rosco_filter$event_time[i], v3=customer)`, cada elemento es un nuevo `data.frame`, esto es importante por que nos asegura respetar cada tipo de datos si tenemos una cadena y un número, el `data.frame` o eventualmente una lista, respetara la naturaleza de cada columna.
- finalmente con `do.call(rbind, resultados)` combinamos todos los elementos de la lista `resultados` en un único `data.frame`.
- Entiendo tu código como un ejemplo parcial, lo digo por que tal como está se podría resolver todo sin necesidad de usar ciclos.
- Es una buena práctica, evitar el uso de `c()` o `rbind()` dentro de un `loop` en particular con objetos tipo `data.frame`, la razón es la modificación in-situ del objeto que genera una copia completa con cada iteración y en algunos casos puede provocar problemas serios de performance.

Comment: Al igual que tu considero que quizá utilizando otras forma seria mejor, tal group_by, filter,count. Por otro lado, bajo este contexto,  tu propuesta brinda mejor performance.